# Multiple pages using relay-modern-isomorphic

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-relay, isomorphic-relay

I followed this relay-modern-isomorphic-example tutorial : [Link](https://github.com/robrichard/relay-modern-isomorphic-example)

In that tutorial they have a single page with no routing ,

```js
import express from 'express';
import graphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql';
import nunjucks from 'nunjucks';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server';
import {schema} from './data/schema';
import renderServer from './js/renderServer';
import renderServer2 from './js/renderServer2';
const APP_PORT = 3000;
const GRAPHQL_PORT = 8080;

// Expose a GraphQL endpoint
const graphQLServer = express();
graphQLServer.use('/', graphQLHTTP({schema, pretty: true}));
graphQLServer.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => console.log(
  `GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`
));

// Serve the Relay app
const compiler = webpack({
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js', 'app.js'),
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        test: /\.js$/,
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {filename: 'app.js', path: '/'},
  devtool: 'source-map'
});

const app = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  contentBase: '/public/',
  proxy: {'/graphql': `http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`},
  publicPath: '/js/',
  stats: {colors: true},
});

nunjucks.configure('views', {autoescape: true});

// Serve static resources
app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', renderServer);
app.use('/detailComponent', renderServer2);
app.listen(APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App is now running on http://localhost:${APP_PORT}`);
});
```

In the above code by default it lands on `localhost:3000`, likewise i want to add another page with url `localhost:3000/detailComponent` . But it will showing me the `localhost:3000` page only . So how to do the routing here , can someone clarify me on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the order of the two routes.

When you call `app.use` you're creating middleware, which behaves differently from the method functions like `get` or `post`. [You can read the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for more details, but here's what's effectively happening: For middleware (but not `get`, `post`, etc.) `/` will match *every* route, and because that middleware is defined before `/detailComponent` in your code, it's triggering even when the route is `/detailComponent`.

That said, if you're implementing SSR and implementing multiple routes, you should probably look into routing everything to one endpoint in express and letting a library like React Router take care of the rest. There's plenty of tutorials out there that show how to do that; [here's just one](https://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2017-06-03-reactjs-server-side-rendering-with-router-v4-and-redux/).